# use alpine JS/11ty/nunchucks to only display two dated items

Tags: javascript, alpine.js, eleventy

I have a series of dated events in a json file. I want to display only two events that are happening the soonest relative to today's date. I'm using 11ty and nunchucks and have the following code:

```
<div class="flex-auto lg:w-1/3" x-data="{ currentDate: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10) }">
<h3>Our Next Events</p>
{% for item in events.items %}
{% if loop.index0 < 2 %}
<h4 class="mb-6">{{ item.date | asPostDate  }}<br>{{ item.description | safe }}</h4>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<p class="text-lg"><a class="rounded-sm p-2 bg-yellow-800 px-4 cursor-pointer hover:font-normal px-10 text-md hover:bg-yellow-700 no-underline font-sans text-white" href="/events/#special">see all events</a></p>
</div>
```

This limits the number of events to two.

However, if I add an x-show based on the current date, like `<div x-show="currentDate <= '{{ item.date }}'">`, it's hiding items that have already loaded in the loop, and so, for instance, I have two items right now that load, but one is before today's date, so it only displays a single item.

What's the proper approach to load the list, evaluate the dates, and then limit the list to the two soonest upcoming items?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an auxiliary Alpine.js array variable that tracks the number of shown events. Using the [`x-init` directive](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/init) on each element we can add the current event's date to this array if the number of events does not exceed the maximum. Then in an `x-show` condition we check whether the date is included in the array or not. See a little live example here:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ maxCount: 2,
               events: [],
               //currentDate: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
               currentDate: '2023-04-11', // Use static date for the example
               addEvent(date) {
                 if (this.currentDate <= date && this.events.length < this.maxCount) {
                   this.events.push(date)
                 }
               }}">
               
  <h3>First two event dates from 2023-04-11</h3>
  <div x-init="addEvent('2023-04-10')" x-show="events.includes('2023-04-10')">2023-04-10</div>
  <div x-init="addEvent('2023-04-11')" x-show="events.includes('2023-04-11')">2023-04-11</div>
  <div x-init="addEvent('2023-04-12')" x-show="events.includes('2023-04-12')">2023-04-12</div>
  <div x-init="addEvent('2023-04-13')" x-show="events.includes('2023-04-13')">2023-04-13</div>
  <div x-init="addEvent('2023-04-14')" x-show="events.includes('2023-04-14')">2023-04-14</div>
</div>
```

And the nunjucks template:

```
<div class="flex-auto lg:w-1/3" x-data="{ 
    maxCount: 2,
    events: [],
    currentDate: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10),
    addEvent(date) {
        if (this.currentDate <= date && this.events.length < this.maxCount) {
          this.events.push(date)
        }
    }}">
    <h3>Our Next Events</p>
    {% for item in events.items %}
    <h4 class="mb-6" 
      x-init="addEvent('{{ item.date }}')"
      x-show="events.includes('{{ item.date }}')">
    {{ item.date | asPostDate  }}<br>{{ item.description | safe }}
    </h4>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```